# How to edit my query to make a proper IF / Join statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My structure is explained as follow:
I have 2 tables, `alerts_conditions` and `alerts_list`

What I want to do is a query that will look in both tables, but sometimes the information will be gathered from the one table only, and sometimes it will be from both.

My query looks if an `id` is found on `alerts_conditions` and/or on `alerts_list`.

The `id` is always found on `alerts_list` table.
So, if the `id` is found on `alerts_conditions` that means it has also a row in `alerts_list`.

But, as mentioned earlier, there are cases that the `id` will be only found on `alerts_list`.

For now, if the `id` is found only on `alerts_list` I get mixed data. 
My question is

1. how can I change my query so when the id is **only** found on `alerts_list`, the columns of the `alerts_conditions` to be presented as empty ?
2. and when the `id` is found in **both** tables to get the data from both?

In this case, number 50 is the `id`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   alerts_conditions, 
       alerts_list 
WHERE  (alerts_conditions.alerts_conditions_alert = 50 OR alerts_list.alerts_id=50)
       AND alerts_conditions.company_id = 1 
LIMIT  1
```

**NOTE**

the `company_id` has nothing to do with the question, and must be left out of any clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to write this is to put the condition on `alerts_conditions` in the `on` clause

```
SELECT ac.*, al.*
FROM alerts_list al LEFT JOIN
     alerts_conditions ac
     ON ac.alerts_conditions_alert = al.alerts_id AND
        ac.company_id = 1 
WHERE al.alerts_id = 50
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT al.*, ac.* 
FROM   alerts_list al
LEFT JOIN alerts_conditions ac ON (al.alerts_id=ac.alerts_conditions_alert)
WHERE  al.alerts_id=50
       AND (
         ac.alerts_conditions_alert is NULL 
         OR 
         ac.company_id = 1
       )
LIMIT  1
```

In case if there is no additional information in `alerts_conditions` its fields will be equal to NULL, otherwise company_id will be checked to match.

Comment: Hi, I get this: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RIGHT JOIN alerts_conditions ac ON (al.alerts_id=ac.alerts_conditions_alert)WH' at line 3

Comment: I have updated my question, by adding a clearer description.
For now, if the id is found only on alerts_list I get mixed data. My question is

1. how can I change my query so when the id is only found on alerts_list, the columns of the alerts_conditions to be presented as empty ?

2.and when the id is found in both tables to get the data from both?

Comment: Did you try my query? I believe it answers updated question

Comment: I have tested your answer. If the `id` is on both tables, it works. Otherwise if it is only on `alerts_list` I get empry output

Comment: Updated, check again, pls